# Android Unit Tests : Mock context that also returns a looper

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-context, android-looper

Here is my sample code :
**SomeClass.java**

```
public class SomeClass {
    public SomeClass(Context mContext) {
        final Looper looper = mContext.getMainLooper();
        Handler mHandler = new Handler(looper);
    }
}
```

**SomeClassTest.java**

```
public class SomeClassTest {
    private SomeClass mSomeClass;

    @Mock
    private Context mContext;

    @before
    public void setup(){
        mSomeClass = new SomeClass(mContext);
    }
}
```

The above code generates a `NullPointerException` at the line `final Looper looper = mContext.getMainLooper();` in `SomeClass`.

How can I setup the mock context object to avoid this exception ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Mockito, you can add mock behavior to mock objects:

```
public class SomeClassTest {
    private SomeClass mSomeClass;
    private Looper mLooper;

    @before
    public void setup(){
        mLooper = mock(Looper.class);
        Context ctx = mock(Context.class);
        when(ctx.getMainLooper()).thenReturn(mLooper);
        mSomeClass = new SomeClass(mContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: **Important update :** For some reason, this solution stopped working because `Looper` is a final class. Not sure how it was working before, but as a work around I created package `android.os` in my `test` directory and had to create an empty class `Looper.java`(not keeping this final) in this package to basically shadow the actual `android.os.Looper` class. The whole thing started working again.

Comment: I do know about that but somehow I am not able to get it's new engine working for me despite following the steps. Decided not to invest too much time in that since I don't really need that functionality.